# Is it possible to reconnect to database table object in R

Tags: r, dbplyr

Suppose I create a database connection:

```
con = dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"), 
        username = "username", 
        password = "password", 
        dbname = "dbname")
```

And create a lazy tibble connection to a particular table in the database:

```
particular_table = tbl(con, "particular_table")
```

After a time, a connection to database is lost.
Is there any way how to re-establish the connection using a new connection (by rerunning the code for `con`) but with the old `particular_table` object? Or do I always need to re-assign the object with a new connection by running the second code again?

Comment: Maybe the `pool` package could take care of it automatically https://rstudio.github.io/pool/ . It should be a drop-in replacement of `con` in `tbl()`

Comment: Thanks Aurèle, but I could not make it work with pool either. I think once the connection is closed, the behavior of pool does not differ from the classical database connection. But I found out that rewriting connection inside nested tbl object does the trick: particular_table[["src"]][["con"]] = con.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is stored inside a nested list in `tbl` object.

You can rewrite the connection by assigning it the new `con` object. After that, business goes as usual.

```
con = dbConnect(dbDriver("Oracle"), 
        username = "username", 
        password = "password", 
        dbname = "dbname")

particular_table[["src"]][["con"]] = con
```